# OpenVPN causes my internet to not work

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I pay $6/mo for nVPN, a paid VPN service.

A few days ago, it stopped working. When I connected my internet would just cut out. The *instant* I disconnected my internet would turn back on.

Now, when I say internet disconnects, I mean that skype goes to the grey swirling arrow thing, I disconnect from the IRC I'm in, no websites (inc. google) load, etc. Windows still claims to be connected.

[Click me to see a log from nVPN](http://pastebin.com/Nk9K086E)

Comment: And the question is ......?

Comment: How do I fix this issue.

Comment: What is the output of `route print` when OpenVPN is connected? It's not setting up the gateway correctly.

Comment: Have you asked nVPN? Maybe they have issues at their end?